# Is Facebook Open Graph metadata tags documented any in detail anywhere?

Tags: metadata, facebook-opengraph

Facebook recommends I add the metadata tags to my open graph.  But are there more details documented anywhere?  Such as http://ogp.me/ns#  and http://ogp.me/ns/fb#   .  Am I supposed to change those?

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="136682149751451" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"        content="website" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"         content="Put your own URL to the object here" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"       content="Your Open Graph object title" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"       content="http://ogp.me/logo.png" /> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="Your Open Graph object description" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at the protocol page http://ogp.me/ and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/

> But are there more details documented anywhere? Such as http://ogp.me/ns# and http://ogp.me/ns/fb# .

You aren't supposed to change those, those are the namespaces needed for `fb` and `og`